# C# unicode probem

Tags: c#

```
public class Charest 
{
 public static void Main(string []args)
 {
  int ch1, ch2;ch1 = 65;
  ch2 = 'B';
  Console.WriteLine(ch1+' '+ch1);
 }
}
```

**How is it 164?**

it should be 65+65 =130 right?

Comment: Space is encoded as 0x20, or 32 in decimal, so you are calculating `65 + 32 + 65`, which is 162, not 164, nor 130. Are you sure you posted the correct code? The current code would print 162.

Answer (score 0):

Space has a value of 32 so when you add up the ch1 and ch1 along with space, you get 162.

```
int a, b;
a = 65;
b = 'B'; // Decimal / Integer Value = 66
Console.WriteLine(a + ' ' + a);
Console.WriteLine(a + ' ' + b);
Console.WriteLine(a + b);
Console.WriteLine(0 + ' ');

// Prints
162
163
131
32
```

> [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) for reference to characters and their decimal values.

[image: Values of B and Space from ASCII table]

Comment: `add up the ch1 and ch2 along with space` That's not what the OP adds up, look more closely ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It should be 162 not 165. Space value is 32. So Sum is 65 + 32 + 65 = 162